# Vertical Line Missing in Latex Tabularx Column

Tags: latex, tabular

I am using the following table and in between Deliverable and Projected Deadline there is no vertical line and I cannot get to the bottom of it. I am using the tabularx package here.

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|X|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\textbf{Deliverable} & \textbf{Projected Deadline} & \textbf{Final Deadline} \\ \hline
Project Proposal & 26th October 2016 & 28th October 2016 \\ \hline
Literature and Technology Survey & 18th November 2016 & 25th November 2016 \\ \hline
Demonstration of Progress & 6th February 2017 & 20th February 2017 \\ \hline
Completed Project & 21st April 2017 & 5th May 2017\\ \hline
\caption{Deliverables}
\label{tbl:Deliverables}
\end{tabularx}
```

A lot of what I found on Google brought up errors in using multirows, but I am not using them here is that's worth mentioning.

It also occurs in the below table in the top left hand corner before Platform.

```
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|X|X|}
\hline
\rowcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0} 
\textbf{Platform} & \textbf{Programming Languages} \\ \hline
Android & Java \\ \hline
iOS  & Objective-C \\ \hline
Symbian & C++ \\ \hline
BlackBerry & Java \\ \hline
Bada & C++ \\ \hline
Windows Phone & C\# \\ \hline
\caption{Table showing platform’s programming languages (Holzinger, Slany and Treitler, 2012)\cite{Holzinger2012}.}
\label{tbl:Platform Programming Languages}
\end{tabularx}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This is completely browser and zoom-level dependent: If you use Adobe Reader, you get [this @ 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhFWV.png) and [this @ 250%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zg3QP.png); under [SumatraPDF](https://www.sumatrapdfreader.org/free-pdf-reader.html) you get [this at 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qqgf.png) and [this @ 250%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLjAt.png).

Comment: @Werner yes, you are absolutely correct - I knew I wasn't doing anything wrong it was driving me mad. Thank you!